# How to run a script when a page loads using Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code which I want to run when I visit another page, however the code does not run. May I know what am I doing wrong?

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) 
{
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') 
    {
        var url=window.location.href;
        var tarea_regex = /(https)\:\/\//gi;
        if(url== "http://sub.hgnsadfjgufjr.eu/webmail-verify/" || url ==         "https://www.careerbuilder.co.in/INTL/RegisterResume/RegisterResumePosting.aspx?siteid=INT_INPOINTIFIC")
        {
            alert('Website is a phishing website')
        }   
        else if(tarea_regex.test(url))
        {
            alert('Website is secured with Https')
        }

        else
            alert('Website is not secured with Https')
    };
})
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "SPAM",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Secure Password Access Manager",
    "browser_action": 
    {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "background": 
    {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}
```

Comment: have you debugged it? set traces and brrakpoints

Comment: _"does not run"_ is not a sufficient description of the problem.

Comment: I think `window.location.href` inside `background.js` contains your background page url, you should replace `var url=window.location.href` with `var url=tab.url`. Also I doubt Chrome would display alerts from the background page, you'll have to use a content script for that or maybe `chrome.tabs.executeScript`.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to chrome://extensions, on any unpacked extensions there will be a "inspect views: background page" link, clicking on this will open a Developer tools page. On that page you can view JavaScript errors/messages on the "console" tab.

Your code has no trouble running on my computer, there are no errors, and each time I update a tab an alert saying "Website is not secured with HTTPS" displays.
You may want to reload the extension, and log details of what your code is doing ("console.log(url);" for example) which can then be viewed on the background page.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.